# How to send Vue Image Object to Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, controller, vuejs3

I'm trying to send an `image object` from vue frontend to laravel controller, so that it can be stored in the public storage but the image gets destroyed. The stored image file can't be opened and shows an error.

In this component:

```
<input v-if="!state.image" class="input-file" type="file" @change="onFileChange">
```

these functions convert the input image to `base64` format:

```
const createImage = (file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        state.image = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

const onFileChange = (e) => {
    state.path = e.target.files[0].name
    const files = e.target.files;
    if (!files.length)
        return;
    createImage(files[0]);
}
```

and send it via `ajax` request:

```
axios.post('/store', state)
    .then(res => {
        state.error = false
        router.push({name: 'artwork'})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        state.error = true
        setTimeout(() => state.error = false, 5000)
});
```

to **`MediaController.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Artwork;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class MediaController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $artwork = new Artwork;

        $artwork->name = $request->name;
        $artwork->path = '/storage/app/public/' . $request->path;
        $artwork->save();

        Storage::disk('public')->put($request->path, $request->image);

        return response()->json(null, 200);
    }
}
```

It looks like the `base64 image data` in `$request->image` turns out broken and is saved in `/storage/app/public/1.jpg`.

How can I get the image from the vue component to the controller and then to the public storage without breaking it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured that `vue` encodes the image to `base64` so the solution was to decode it back in `laravel`.

I had to add these lines to **`MediaController.php`**:

```
$image = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $request->image);

Storage::disk('public')->put($request->path, base64_decode($image));
```